# Live Streaming - WebRTC to RTMP

Tags: facebook, webrtc, rtmp, live-streaming

I am working on a live streaming project and came across many services like Wowza, Dacast, Ant etc. The one suits for my requirement uses RTMP protocol and so I will have to use an encoding software like OBS to publish the stream. I actually want to publish the stream from browser/iOS/Android.

I came across [this](https://atscaleconference.com/videos/facebook-live-video-for-news-feed-part-2/) FB presentation and seems like they are using RTMP protocol. FB is successfully doing the broadcast from the browser somehow.

Can I get an insight into how the things would be working with FB / similar RTMP based live streaming apps? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, there is no conversion, Facebook just supports webrtc.

Comment: @szatmary - Thanks for the reply. This question actually came up after watching the presentation under https://atscaleconference.com/videos/facebook-live-video-for-news-feed-part-2/. The presenter tells that FB is using RTMP. I was just wondering how FB broadcasts video from the browser if the protocol is RTMP!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook supports RTMP ingest of video (used by people who utilize the Live API), as well as WebRTC ingest for browser clients.

RTMP is not used as a distribution protocol.  For that, there is DASH.